# Does asio::streambuf support positioning (i.e. multiple input streams)?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In my project, I'm using [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) and [asio](http://think-async.com/Asio) (non-boost). The serialization functions of cereal expect to operate on a stream (`std::ostream` for example).

Serialization is not a problem and neither is deserialization - usually. This is how my deserialize function looks like:

```
template <typename ...Types>
auto deserialize(asio::streambuf& buf, Types& ...data) -> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Types) > 0)>
{
    std::istream is(&buf);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive ar(is);
    ar(data...);
}
```

which works perfectly fine, except that `is` causes the data in buffer to be destroyed once it has been read.

Is it possible to read from `buf` without freeing its data (so I can deserialize the whole buffer again)? Neither `streambuf::pubseekpos` nor `std::istream::seekg` work to reset the position.

Comment: Why do you need to read the buffer multiple times? Parsing takes time, may be you could just copy the just parsed objects, or, better, reuse them?

Comment: Basically there are multiple handlers called (event based system). And one handler may start to partially deserialize the buffer and then decides to not handle the message. In that case the buffer should be reset to the start so the next handler can use it.